# Changing content via javascript on load

Tags: javascript, html

I added the following script to my html body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function customizeNavbar() {
        var d = document.getElementById("navwrap");
        d.classList.add("container");
        var e = document.getElementById("navhead");
        e.classList.add("container");
    }
</script>
<script onload="customizeNavbar();"></script>
```

It's not running my function on load.

Clicking some element `<div onclick="customizeNavbar();" />` behaves as expected.

What can I do to get this page to run my script on load?

**Context**

This is found *in* the body element. It's changing the navbar of a master layout to avoid having to update the master layout. The navbar comes before this script is reached.

Not sure why this is getting down-voted. Yet to have anyone provide a good explanation or a solution that actually works.

Comment: The second script tag has no content, and will never load. You shouldn't use the load event of the first script tag either

Comment: Why should I not? It appears to work. What problems does that cause?

Comment: It's exactly the same as just removing the function wrapper and the onload handler, so why use it ?

Comment: I doubt an inline script would trigger `onload` at all, it is fired after finished loading of _external_ resources only.

Comment: If the script is within the body and after the elements it's referring, a very simple solution would be either to simply call `customizeNavbar()` at the end of the script, or use an [IIFE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8228308/1169519).

Comment: Are you trying to get the function to run when a specific object loads? Because if you want it to run on the page load then you have viable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

you must try that :

```
<script id="someId" type="text/javascript">
    function customizeNavbar() {
        var d = document.getElementById("navwrap");
        d.classList.add("container");
        var e = document.getElementById("navhead");
        e.classList.add("container");
    }
window.onload = setTimeout(customizeNavbar, 1);
//or
document.getElementById("someId").onload = setTimeout(customizeNavbar, 1); //and you can put it anywhere in your code i think
</script>
```

the setTimeout of 1ms is a little overated, but we're never sure enough

**Edit:**

The onload event occurs after an element is charged that's why you have to put it on the same element.
source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: window.onload is called at the end of the DOM loading and elt.onload is called at the end of this element loading.
Then in both cases the full DOM or the needed DOM is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onload` event of the window, not the script element.

```
function customizeNavbar() {
 ...
}

window.onload = customizeNavbar;
```

The `onload` event of a script doesn't necessarily tell you if the whole DOM is ready, only if that particular script loaded, and since you used it on an empty script, it will never load.

Comment: This is a correct way and convetional way to do it without extra libraries. You got my vote.

Comment: @JosephNields If this doesn't work for you, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: It displays it incorrectly to start, and then it makes changes. I don't want that. It should display correctly to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function customizeNavbar() {
        var d = document.getElementById("navwrap");
        d.classList.add("container");
        var e = document.getElementById("navhead");
        e.classList.add("container");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="customizeNavbar();"></body>
```

put the onload on the body

Comment: I can't put the onload on the body. This is within the body.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `customizeNavbar` in the `onload` event of the body element, not in the `onload` of a separate `script`. Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onload):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Page is loaded");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, `myFunction` is defined inside a script and is `assigned` to the `onload` event of the `body`. As you can see, it works! Now, your code should be changed the following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function customizeNavbar() {
                var d = document.getElementById("navwrap");
                d.classList.add("container");
                var e = document.getElementById("navhead");
                e.classList.add("container");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--some HTML-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following allows the function to be called immediately when encountered, and then to be called again once the window is fully loaded, in case the DOM has not yet loaded, if that is really a concern.

```
<script type="text/javascript" onload="customizeNavbar();">
    function customizeNavbar() {
        var d = document.getElementById("navwrap");
        d.classList.add("container");
        var e = document.getElementById("navhead");
        e.classList.add("container");
    } window.onload = customizeNavbar;
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Due to jQuery's popularity, I've responded using jQuery methods. Once you've [included jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) to your HTML webpage, all you need to do is change your script to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    function customizeNavbar() {
      $('#navwrap').addClass('container');
      $('#navhead').addClass('container');
    }

    customizeNavbar();
  });
</script>
```

For more information, take a look at the [$( document ).ready() documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Using the above code, you don't even need the onclick part of your code. In my opinion, it saves time.

Comment: This is semi-semi. First you write `$(document).ready()` instead of looking up the non-jquery way, but then you kept the non-jquery  `document.getElementById("navhead");` instead of `$('#navhead')`. Either all-jQuery or no-jQuery is my opinion.

Comment: @DanFromGermany thank you sir for your explanation. I hate it when people downvote, then don't explain why. I will keep your answer in mind. You are absolutely correct.